# Inserir novos campos dinamicamente, sendo um ao lado do outro

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net

Ola, estou precisando sanar a seguinte dúvida. Tenho uma aplicação Web, feito em Asp.Net, em uma nova funcionalidade tenho 6 campos fixos contendo uma combo, um espaço para visualização da foto e um input e caso o cliente queira adicionar mais um campo, ele pode clicar no botão Adicionar Foto e será inserido um novo campo contendo os mesmos itens. Até ai tudo bem, isso está funcionando perfeitamente (em questão de preenchimento automático das combos, input e visualização das fotos. Só que ao adicionar um novo campo, ele deveria inserir os campos um ao lado do outro, mas acaba inserindo um embaixo do outro (conforme figura). O trecho que insiro os campos dinamicamente está aqui em baixo:

```js
var contadorID = 6;
var contador = 0;

  $("#btnAdicionaFoto").click(function (ev) {
            AdicionarCampo();
   });
        
function AdicionaCampo(){
var html = "";    
    html += "<div class='Moldura'>";
    html += "<select class='form - control' id='cboTipoFoto" + contadorID + "' style='width: 480px;'>";
    html += " </select>";
    html += " <div class='Moldura2'>";
    html += " <img id='img" + contadorID + "' style = 'width: 480px; height: 360px' /> ";
    html += " </div>";
    html += " <input id='btnUpload" + contadorID + "' type = 'file' accept = 'image / ' class='btn btn - info' /> ";
    html += "</div>";        

    if (contador <4)
        $("#adicaoinput1").append(html);
    else if (contador < 7)
        $("#adicaoinput2").append(html);
}
```

```html
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
        <div class="Moldura">
            <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto3">
            </select>
            <div class="Moldura2">
                <img id="img3" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
            </div>
            <input id="btnUpload3" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
        <div class="Moldura">
            <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto4">
            </select>
            <div class="Moldura2">
                <img id="img4" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
            </div>
            <input id="btnUpload4" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
        <div class="Moldura">
            <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto5">
            </select>
            <div class="Moldura2">
                <img id="img5" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
            </div>
            <input id="btnUpload5" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
        <div id="adicaoinput1" >
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
        <div id="adicaoinput2" >
        </div>
    </div>
     <div>
        <button type="button" id="btnAdicionaFoto" class="btn btn-info">ADICIONAR FOTOS</button>
    </div>
```

Ao invés de ficar desta forma (como a imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Está ficando desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como resolvo isso?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É porque você não está inserindo dentro de uma `div.row`. A classe `.row` irá agrupar as divs uma ao lado da outra, como acontece nas divs dentro da primeira `div.row` que você colocou.

Você pode resolver colocando as id's nas `div.row` e remover as divs filhas:

```
<div id="adicaoinput1" class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
</div>
<div id="adicaoinput2" class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
</div>
```

Exemplo:

```js
var contadorID = 6;
var contador = 0;

  $("#btnAdicionaFoto").click(function (ev) {
            AdicionarCampo();
   });
        
function AdicionarCampo(){
var html = "";    
    html += "<div class='Moldura'>";
    html += "<select class='form - control' id='cboTipoFoto" + contadorID + "' style='width: 480px;'>";
    html += " </select>";
    html += " <div class='Moldura2'>";
    html += " <img id='img" + contadorID + "' style = 'width: 480px; height: 360px' /> ";
    html += " </div>";
    html += " <input id='btnUpload" + contadorID + "' type = 'file' accept = 'image / ' class='btn btn - info' /> ";
    html += "</div>";        

    if (contador <4)
        $("#adicaoinput1").append(html);
    else if (contador < 7)
        $("#adicaoinput2").append(html);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
  <div class="Moldura">
      <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto3">
      </select>
      <div class="Moldura2">
          <img id="img3" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
      </div>
      <input id="btnUpload3" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
  </div>
  <div class="Moldura">
      <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto4">
      </select>
      <div class="Moldura2">
          <img id="img4" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
      </div>
      <input id="btnUpload4" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
  </div>
  <div class="Moldura">
      <select class="form-control" id="cboTipoFoto5">
      </select>
      <div class="Moldura2">
          <img id="img5" style="width: 480px; height: 360px" />
      </div>
      <input id="btnUpload5" type="file" accept="image/" class="btn btn-info" />
  </div>
</div>
 <div id="adicaoinput1" class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
 </div>
 <div id="adicaoinput2" class="row" style="padding-left: 10px!important;">
 </div>
  <div>
     <button type="button" id="btnAdicionaFoto" class="btn btn-info">ADICIONAR FOTOS</button>
 </div>
```

Comment: Obrigado, deu certo aqui.

Comment: Legal, amigo! Se puder marcar ✔ na resposta, pode ajudar pessoas no futuro. Abs!

Comment: Feito e mais uma vez obrigado.